# How to convert Doc And docx file to html in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I want to Get Docx and doc file content in html format, but i don't want to store file on server means while upload file i want to get content of file and convert it to in html stream?

```
how can i achive this:-

private IEnumerable<string> GetFileInfo(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    retur files.InputStream;
}
```

Without upload file i want to return content of File in html format...

Please help

Comment: you need some sort of library for this espesialy for .doc format.

Comment: can you suggest me any?